# Generic @ExceptionHandler for Spring webapp with different return values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Servlet Exception handler for Spring which can either return an  html (if the request was for html page) or a json (for REST api calls). The html part works well because I have configured a HandlebarsViewResolver, thus the "else" part in the code below searches for exception.hbs and works well. 
But when I try to set MappingJacksonJsonView then spring tries to find MappingJacksonJsonView.hbs and does not actually use MappingJacksonJsonView to convert the POJO (jsonErrorObject) to json and return it.

Could somebody help me out and let me know how do I make this generic exception handler work which can either return a handlerbars view or a json via MappingJacksonJsonView?

Java code

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus (value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ModelAndView handleAnyException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    if (request.getHeader("Accept").contains("application/json")) {
            mav.setViewName("myJSON", "result", jsonErrorObject);
        } else {
            mav.setViewName("exception");
            mav.addObject("exceptionMessage", jsonErrorObject.getResDescr());
        }
    return mav;
}
```

servlet.xml

```
<bean id="hbsViewResolver" class="com.github.jknack.handlebars.springmvc.HandlebarsViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/hbs/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".hbs" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean name="myvr" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref local="hbsViewResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean name="myJSON" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```